# UTF-16 behave differently on OSX vs Windows

Tags: java, macos, csv, selenium, utf-16

I created a program that takes a csv file, read its values and based on the values im doing some actions with selenium webdriver.

The problem is that im using a os x, and other people use it on windows, and before you upload the file you need to edit some rows(not all the time), and then the formatting is changing and it causes problems, but sometime even without changing anything the problems occurs...but on the mac there are no problems...

Im using utf-16 since the website im downloading it from is giving me utf-16 csv's. this is part of my code:

```
object CsvDataSource extends DataSource {

  import com.github.tototoshi.csv.{CSVFormat, QUOTE_MINIMAL, Quoting}

  implicit object MYFormat extends CSVFormat {
    val delimiter: Char = '\t'
    val quoteChar: Char = '"'
    val escapeChar: Char = '"'
    val lineTerminator: String = "\r\n"
    val quoting: Quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
    val treatEmptyLineAsNil: Boolean = false
  }

  override def read(file: File): Seq[Map[String, String]] = {

    val reader = CSVReader.open(file, "UTF-16")(MYFormat)

    reader.iteratorWithHeaders.toList
  }
}
```

So to use my program you need to download a file using some website and this website giving the csv in utf-16, anf then upload it to my program and the magic is done. but on my mac it works fine, and in pc that runs windows sometime we get formatting issues...does someone knows how to fix this and to make it compatible to the two op systems?

example issue:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ParseException: Unparseable date: "1-DEC-15"]]
```

Most of the time is this issue, but sometime when I fix the date format it still dosent work, sometime it does. I dont know why im getting this issue sometimes cause the format is fine...the date IS suppose to be "1-DEC-15" like this. I need to get it in this format and return it differently, this is howo i do it:

```
private def changeDateFormat(dateInString: String): String = {
    val inputFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")
    val resultFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

    val date: Date = inputFormat.parse(dateInString)
    resultFormat.format(date)
  }
```

Comment: Could you post the formatting issues you get with Windows (an example) it could help to understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: The easy way: ask users to edit the UTF-16 text file using a decent text editor, for instance Notepad++, which can deal with UTF-8 with or without BOM, UTF-16 Big Endian and UTF-16 Little Endian.

Comment: @user3272243 done, edited it

Comment: What's the locale? `DEC` is not a valid month in all languages.